# How to speed up combinations code

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

```
from itertools import combinations

for comb in combinations(range(1, 70), 5):
    for PB in combinations(range(1, 27), 1):
        if PB[0] in range(1, 27):
            a = open(f"PowerBall{PB[0]}.txt", "a")
            a.write(str(comb + PB))
            a.write("\n")
            print("\r", f"on: {comb + PB}", end="")
```

> Trying to find all combination for those set of ranges.

Comment: The faster speedup: rethink what you're doing because chances are you don't need this and actually just need to get a particular value every time you need it.

Comment: I have the same need, I tried to do multi-core or GPU computing, but it was just an idea, it didn't work out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps open all 26 files. Then generate the combinations just once and write each one to all the files. Use `contextlib.ExitStack()` to ensure all the files get closed. Something like this (untested):

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from itertools import combinations

with ExitStack() as stack:

    files = [stack.enter_context(open(f"PowerBall{i}.txt", "a")) for i in range(1,27)]

    for comb in combinations(range(1, 70), 5):
        for pb, pb_file in enumerate(files, 1):
            print(*comb, pb, file=pb_file, sep=", ")
```

The `files = [...]` list comprehension opens all 26 files and pushes them onto the ExitStack. When the `with` statement exits, the `__exit__()` method is called on all items on the stack, which for a file causes it to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

- looping over 11238513 items (the number of `range(70)` combinations of length 5) and creating/opening and writing to those file in each operation is expensive. One way to speed that up is to do that asynchronous (eg using the `aiofile` functionality in Python). I did a small test using `aiofile` but I got a *slower* performance compared to your current code...
- Switch both for loops. This way, you can create a file once, open it *before* the inner loop and then write all combinations to that file in one pass. This will save a lot of file open/close operations.
- A small speedup at the cost of some memory might be achieved by creating the file contents in memory and write it to the disk at once. E.g.: create a string with the file contents, append the data to the string. And after the inner (combi) loop, write it to a file. I did a small test doing this, but I didn't get a substantial performance boost from it. Apparently Python handles file writes quite efficiently.
- You don't explicitly close the file handle. Use a `with` context to automatically close the file at the end of the `with` block. Eg: `with with open('file_path', 'w') as file:`
- the PB for loop doesn’t need `itertools`. Just loop over the range.
- you’re using capitals for a variable (PB). By PEP8, variable names in capitals are constants.
- Use meaningful variable names. `combi` and `a` not really good variable names.
- the if statement is useless. Since PB is looping over that same range, PB[0] will always be in that range.

This results in something like this (check the file output contents; this might not be exactly what you're after, but you get the idea:

```
for pb in range(1, 27):
    with open(f'PowerBall{pb}_sync.txt', 'a') as file:
        for comb in combinations(range(1, 70), 5):
            file.write(f'{comb}{pb}\non: {comb}{pb}')
```